# How tell Safari to open new tab instead of a window

Tags: safari

How do I tell Safari to always open links that want a new window in a new tab?

I know I can use cmd-click to do this but that's not what I want.

There has to be a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Safari preferences (<kbd>⌘ ,</kbd>) to change this setting, you can use automatically or always for opening pages in new tabs instead of new windows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In safari preferences (command + ,) on the "Tabs" tab you can set this options.

Or you can right click the link and choose the option you want. Or depending on your current configuration command + click on the link could open the link on a new page or a new tab.